# How to add data to the queue log?

Tags: mysql, asterisk, freepbx

I have freepbx, Asterisk version 13.32.0 built by mockbuild @ jenkins7.
We need to include into queue_log file additional field with CallerID number. How can i do this?
Right now I have a table on mysql - queue_log, but I want to see the Callerid number. Is it possible?
[image: Workbanch]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ENTERQUEUE event's data2 is callerid.

There are no ways add more info, except you can use QueueLog app to add custom info.

Comment: HI, what is custom info in the current context?

Comment: Anything you want to save to table. http://prntscr.com/uzwilz